# Average squared Hamiltonian of linear combination of eigenfunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, wavefunction, hamiltonian

As part of a larger problem, I am trying to find the average squared Hamiltonian of a system with eigenfunctions $\psi_{1,1}$, $\psi_{1,2}$, $\psi_{2,1}$, $\psi_{2,2}$ and the following wave function:

$$ \Psi\left(\mathbf{r};t=0\right)=c\sum_{j=1}^2 \psi_{ij}\left(\mathbf{r}\right) $$

The problem defines the following operators:

\begin{align*}
    \hat{H}\psi_{ij} &= iE\psi_{ij} \\
    \hat{Q}\psi_{ij} &= jQ\psi_{ij}
\end{align*}

where $ \{i,j\}\in\mathbb{R} $. I have already calculated that

\begin{align*}
    p\left(\mathbf{r}\right) &= c\,\left(\langle\psi_{i1}|\psi_{i1}\rangle + \langle\psi_{i1}|\psi_{i2}\rangle + \langle\psi_{i2}|\psi_{i1}\rangle + \langle\psi_{i2}|\psi_{i2}\rangle\right) \\
    1 &= c\,\left(1 + 0 + 0 + 1\right) \\
    c &= \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}
    \langle\Psi|\hat{H}|\Psi\rangle &= \langle\psi_{i1}|\hat{H}|\psi_{i1}\rangle + \langle\psi_{i1}|\hat{H}|\psi_{i2}\rangle + \langle\psi_{i2}|\hat{H}|\psi_{i1}\rangle + \langle\psi_{i2}|\hat{H}|\psi_{i2}\rangle \\
    &= \frac{i}{2}\left(E_{i1}\langle\psi_{i1}|\psi_{i1}\rangle + E_{i2}\langle\psi_{i1}|\psi_{i2}\rangle + E_{i2}\langle\psi_{i2}|\psi_{i1}\rangle + E_{i2}\langle\psi_{i2}|\psi_{i2}\rangle\right) \\
    &= \frac{i}{2}\left(E_{i1}\langle\psi_{i1}|\psi_{i1}\rangle + 0 + 0 + E_{i2}\langle\psi_{i2}|\psi_{i2}\rangle\right) \\
    &= \frac{i}{2}\left(E_{i1}+E_{i2}\right)
\end{align*}

However, I'm not quite sure how to scale it up to $ \langle\Psi|\hat{H}^2|\Psi\rangle $. I am putting forward the assumption that $ \langle\hat{H}^2\rangle - \langle\hat{H}\rangle^2 $ should = 0 since I am working with eigenfunctions, and that therefore

\begin{align*}
    \langle\Psi|\hat{H}^2|\Psi\rangle &= \,?!? \\
    &= \left(\frac{i}{2}\left(E_{i1}+E_{i2}\right)\right)^2 \\
    &= \frac{i^2}{4}\left(E_{i1}^2 + E_{i1}E_{i2} + E_{i2}^2\right)
\end{align*}

But I am unsure how to prove it, hence the ?!?.

Comment: what is $p(\boldsymbol{r})$?  Moreover, is the sum in $\Psi(\boldsymbol{r};t=0)$ only over $j$ or is it also over $i$?  If there is no sum over $i$, why to you need this index on your $\psi_{ij}$?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero - $p\left(\mathbf{r}\right)$ is the probability at location $\mathbf{r}$, it's just for normalizing. The sum is only over $j$, but according to my peers the $i$ must stay. I think my main source of confusion is the $E$ - my teacher omits the index both in the assignment and his notes, but when I look in the Griffiths it's almost always defined as $E_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is not quite correct.  Your $p(r)$ should be
$$
p(\boldsymbol{r})=cc^*\left(
\langle \psi_{i1}\vert\psi_{i1}\rangle + \langle \psi_{i1}\vert \psi_{i2}\rangle
+\langle \psi_{i2}\vert\psi_{i1}\rangle + \langle \psi_{i2}\vert \psi_{i2}\right)
$$
from which you find that $c=\frac{e^{i\varphi}}{\sqrt{2}}$ for arbitrary phase $\varphi$.  You may choose $\varphi=0$ for convenience but you don't have to.

Then,
\begin{align}
\hat H \left(c\sum_{j=1}^2\psi_{ij}(\boldsymbol{r})\right)&=\left(c\sum_{j=1}^2i E\psi_{ij} (\boldsymbol{r})\right)=i E\left(c\sum_{j=1}^2\psi_{ij} (\boldsymbol{r})\right)\, ,\\
\hat H^2 \left(c\sum_{j=1}^2\psi_{ij}(\boldsymbol{r})\right)=
\hat H\left(\hat H \left(c\sum_{j=1}^2\psi_{ij}(\boldsymbol{r})\right)\right)&=i^2 E^2\left(c\sum_{j=1}^2\psi_{ij} (\boldsymbol{r})\right)\, .
 \end{align}
 You can use orthogonality to finish the calculation.  Note that all  your states with same $i$ have the same energy and this should produce a simplified result.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got confused with $E$ and forgot that $c$ is part of the inner product. The problem also defined $c\in\mathbb{R}^+$, so $cc^* \simeq c^2$. Another peer suggested simply placing the summation directly in bra-kets, so I ended up with this: https://i.imgur.com/KaYdlun.png

Comment: @AgentRev oui c'est exact puisque vos functions d'ondes sont des fonctions propres de l'Hamiltonian avec la meme valeur propre, i.e. la combinaison $\sum_{j=1}^2\psi_{ij}$ est egalement une fonction propre, donc la variance sera $0$.